# Having trouble with making an API request which has retrofit and @POST with two separate ByteArrays

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

So I've an API which allows me to upload two different photos. A full image and a cropped image. Those two photos are in the form of ByteArray's.

This is the body of the API call

```
{
    fullImage: ByteArray,
    croppedImage: ByteArray,
    imageName: String
}
```

*My question here is, how do I upload/send this API request in Android via retrofit?*

This is what I've come up with and it doesn't work. I believe it's because of @Query parameter.

```
@POST("v2/selfie")
fun uploadSelfie(@Query("fullImage") fullImage: ByteArray,
                 @Query("croppedImage") croppedImage: ByteArray,
                 @Query("imageName") hash: String): Completable
```

Comment: `@Query` params map info path variables of HTTP request. You should put your `ByteArray`s into Request Body. You should put your `ByteArray`s into Request Body. Depending on the definition and implementation of your API, of which I cannot be sure, this could be done sending s single object containing your required fields and annotated as `@Body`, or as a Multipart Body.

Comment: @ryfterek Yes, I believe so. My bad. Thanks.